# CUSUM algorithm and first derivative

Tags: change-point

I have a doubt about implementation of CUSUM algorithm. I found a Python implementation [here](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/demotu/BMC/blob/master/notebooks/DetectCUSUM.ipynb).

It is based on a formulation of the CUSUM that basically tracks positive ($g^+$) as well as negative ($g^-$) changes  in a temporal sequence ($x$) and checks them against a preset $threshold$. A change ($t_{alarm}$) is detected when $g^+$ or $g^-$ goes above the threshold. Moreover, a $drift$ terms is introduced to avoid detections of changes in absence of an actual change or a slow drift. According to the author, the CUSUM in this scenario can be formulated as follows:

$
\begin{array}{l l} 
\left\{ \begin{array}{l l} 
s[t] = x[t] - x[t-1] \\
g^+[t] = max\left(g^+[t-1] + s[t]-drift,\; 0\right) \\
g^-[t] = max\left(g^-[t-1] - s[t]-drift,\; 0\right)
\end{array} \right. \\
\\
\; if \;\;\; g^+[t] > threshold \;\;\; or \;\;\;  g^-[t] > threshold: \\
\left\{ \begin{array}{l l} 
t_{talarm}=t \\
g^+[t] = 0 \\
g^-[t] = 0 
\end{array} \right.
\end{array}
$

This formulation seems to me very similar to the "classical" filtered derivative algorithm (as described at section 2.1.4 of *Detection of Abrupt Changes: Theory and Application* by Basseville and Nikiforov), in case of change in mean of a Gaussian sequence, with an integrating filter $\nabla g = x_k - x_{k-N}$ with $N = 1$.

Moreover, the author's formulation appear to be based on the *CUSUM RLS filter*  (section 3.4.4 of *Adaptive Filtering and Change Detection* by 
Gustafsson), that is described as a combination of the CUSUM test and adaptive filtering. Basically, the main idea is to separate the signal $\theta_t$ form the noise $e_t$. Thus, CUSUM is used here as stopping rule on $\theta_t$ surveillance, based on its estimation $\hat{\theta}_t$. The updating of $\hat{\theta}\,$ follows the rule: $$\hat{\theta}_t = \lambda\, \hat{\theta}_{t-1} + (1 - \lambda)\, y_t$$ In this case, $g^+ = max(g^+_{t-1} + \epsilon_t - \nu, 0)$, where $\epsilon_t = y_t - \hat{\theta}_{t-1}$ and $\nu$ represent the drift. So, if I understand well, the algorithm presented by the author is a CUSUM RSL filter with $\lambda = 0$, that is without memory for the filter.

Am I right or am I missing some details? Can it be considered as an implementation of a "plain" CUSUM algorithm?

Another question: What is the best approach in case both $\mu$ of the signal before and after the change are unknown?

Answer (score 4):

The resetting of g+ and g- to zero when the threshold is exceeded is not a part of the classic CUSUM procedure.  The classic CUSUM (per Ewan 1963 https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/00401706.1963.10490055 or Montgomery 1996 [https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Statistical-Quality-Control-Montgomery/dp/0470169923](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470169923) ) would continue to alarm until the shift reverts or the shift was externally identified and remediated somehow, causing the g+/- to decay below the threshold due to the drift term.

As written, a single significant change would cause the algorithm to produce a series of periodic alarms as the g+ series formed a sawtooth wave while being periodically reset by the threshold rule.

Also, since the procedure uses `x[t-1]` as its estimate of the `\mu` of the signal before the change, it is designed to detect fast drifts rather than `\mu` shifts, and significant drifts (compared to the process noise) could well be masked by the process noise.